# User registration/login not working in checkout after patch 8788

Tags: magento-1.9, supee-8788

After installing patch 8788 i received mails from customers that the user registration/login is not working anymore in the checkout. The user login outside the checkout page is still working.

Comment: did you flush the cache directory after patching (by executing rm -rf var/cache/*, not via admin panel)? supee-6788 installed? any log entries?

Answer (score 3):

You're probably missing the now needed formkey in your checkout login form. Add something like `<?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>` (out of my head, actual code might differ slightly) to your checkout template's login `<form>`.

Comment: Thx, but i already tried that without succes.

Comment: can you post the shop url?

Comment: www.bikeaddict.be

Comment: did you revert the patch? when trying to log in during checkout login itself works but i'm redirected to my account page. is this what happens with 8788, too, or what kind of misbehavior did users report?

Comment: The redirect to the account page is also reported. Is it also solved with this: <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey'); ?>

Comment: Problems are, as far as I can tell from my tests, not related to a missing formkey which is submitted correctly. Maybe caching problems (did you `rm -rf` the cache folder after patching?), missing other security updates (notably 6788) resulting in an exception or a conflict with the theme or any third party module. Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 1):

**System > Configuration > (Change to Store View) > Developer**

Open the Developer area and add your IP to the whitelist, then enable the profiler and reload your login page. You should see dotted lines encompassing areas of the website, each with their own directory path for the file being used to load that area.

Check the registration/login page directory path to make sure you are updating the correct .phtml files. You may have an extension that is overriding your registration/login pages but doesn't look any different than the default.

This and **pong**'s answer should solve your issue. Remember to flush cache and reindex after changes like this.